# GTA V: iFruit and Xbox Live

Tags: xbox-network, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-ifruit

I've downloaded iFruit for GTA V and I'm planning on getting the game soon. I don't have an Internet connection at my house. Since I've synced my iFruit, will I need to get online to play GTA V?

Comment: If you don't have an Xbox Live Gold membership nor an internet connection the the iFruit application is literally pointless.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an internet connection to play *GTA 5*, but you do need it to play *GTA Online*.

Without an internet connection you won't be able to take advantage of the *iFruit* app, however. For instance: training Chop in *iFruit* will have no effect in *GTA 5* unless you have an internet connection for both your console and your smartphone/tablet.